# Boiler only runs for 4 minutes then shuts off

Tags: thermostat, boiler

I have a Slant/Fin boiler that's attached to a old White and Rodgers thermostat, typically the boiler only runs for about 4 minutes before it shuts off.

This small period isn't really heating up our 3rd floor, the first and second floors are well heated.

I think I have the anticipator set to the highest setting (see attached).

What can I do to get the top floor warm?

[image: anticipator]

[image: thermostat]

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the regulator/vents on the first and second floors to a lower setting so the thermostat stays on longer so more heat gets to the third floor. Also, check the third floor vents to make sure they're open all the way and regulators are open all the way.

Comment: I think this is good advice, folks mess with controls without realizing they affect other zones. Since the other areas are well heated they need to be throttled down so more makes it to the top.

Comment: Yes, such a simple solution.  I bet it may be the basement door, that's where the boiler is, and we tend to leave it open, AND the thermostat is not far away.  (We just moved into this house by-the-way).  I will give an update tomorrow. Thanks Jack!

Comment: So closed 2 of the 3 regulators on the thermostat floor (the third one needs some work to get closed), and shut the basement door. That allowed the boiler to run for about 6 minutes (it has averaged about 20 degrees the past few days). So that was helpful. Thank you. So now I will post my boiler pipe insulation question.

Comment: @awpawluczkowycz  Make sure to check the regulators on the third floor to be open all the way..